# How to read an MS word(.doc or .docx) file and then and add some text contents to the same file with php

Tags: php, ms-word

I am searching for a solution for this using PHP,

I have word file in my system, I just want to uplaod this file to my website, then i want to add some text into that same word file.

Currently I tried it with file_get_contents, file_put_contents.
But when I opened the file after updating, the contents shows in binary format.

Can any one help??

I tried with this code..

I tried with this code..

```
    if (isset($_POST['form_action']) && (isset($_POST['submitted']) == 1) )
    {
    $data = $_POST['data'];

   $file = 'test.doc';
   $text= $data;
   $text.= file_get_contents($file);
   file_put_contents($file, $text);
```

Comment: There is not a simple answer as a .doc file is not a simple file with text inside, and a .docx file is a archive. Depending on what you exactly want to do, you should have to use a PHP library that will allow you to manipulate .doc or .docx

Comment: Word has a proprietary format, and a quite complex one too. While Word > 2007 uses XML and is easier to crack open (than .doc), if you plan to read .doc you'll face a hard time reading it, unless using the COM api from Microsoft (which means having a Windows system with Word - or the Office Suite - installed I believe)

Comment: Here is a short example using the COM API : http://www.phpbuilder.com/columns/yunus20031124.php3?page=2 And the COM documentation on the PHP.NET : http://php.net/manual/en/book.com.php

Comment: I tried both ways.. but it returns an error.Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Source: Microsoft Word
Description: This command is not available because no document is open.' in D:\wamp\www\docx-file-reader\docx-to-txt-conversion.php on line 24..Is that problem cause because of the file name indicates as Sample.doc[compatibility mode]